# python scripting ,environment variables and openstack

Tags: python, linux, bash, environment-variables, openstack

I'm currently working on jenkins and i want to automate my vm's backup on openstack.

So I found a script that is apparently doing what i want ( https://dev.cloudwatt.com/en/blog/instance-backup-script.html )

To start the program i must do:

```
python backup.py <server_id> <server_name> <weekly|daily> <rotation>
```

It also asks to load some environment variables (on linux ?) containing  the ID, the PASSWORD etc...

I see some inconvenience with thoses environment variables because then the password is stored localy and uncrypted. I may be wrong but the script also send the uncrypted password trough the network ans its a big problem.

If someone can provide any clarification about how is the password sent or if you have any other method.

It must be a dumb question but the script is made for cloudwatt (which is using openstack) and i want to use it on openstack only will it works ?

Sorry for bad english and thank you a lot for any answers,

Tristan.

Comment: this is similar to you log in to StackOverflow and the difference is that when you log in to StackOverflow, you are using a graphical user interface, but when you put the password along with the script, it is through command line tool. So, why log in SO is secure? maybe you wanna google it ;)

Comment: Yes but my browser is logging using https, tbh i dont really how the script is connecting to openstack. But thanks for answer !

Comment: sure, you are welcome. And your browser is logging using https since the SO's web server (apache, nginx, or others) supports SSL. The developer has to configure this. The script you are using is basically a writeup of openstack python client api which is a python wrapper of openstack REST api. Maybe read something like how REST API or API works in general will help.

Comment: thank you, but i have some troubles with the script, i'm still getting errors as output ans i dont know much in python :(